# get Hashmap Item at Kotlin but the Hashmap on Java

Tags: java, android, session, kotlin, hashmap

Can you Help me, i was created the hashmap on **SessionManager.java** now i want to get the item at **ProfileFragment.kt** . The problem is `'EMAIL'` and `'PASSWORD'` not found. How can i solve this issue? Can anyone please help me to solve the issue?

This my `**SessionManager.java**`

```
 public class SessionManager {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        public Context context;
        int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

        private static final String PREF_NAME = "LOGIN";
        private static final String LOGIN = "IS_LOGIN";
        public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
        public static final String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";


        public SessionManager(Context context){
            this.context = context;
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        }

        public void createSession(String Email, String Password){
            editor.putBoolean(LOGIN, true);
            editor.putString("EMAIL", Email);
            editor.putString("PASSWORD", Password);
            editor.apply();
        }

        public boolean isLoggin(){
            return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGIN, false);
        }

        public void checkLogin(){
            if (this.isLoggin()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(i);
                ((MainActivity) context).finish();
            }
        }

        public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetail(){
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put(EMAIL, sharedPreferences.getString(EMAIL, null));
            user.put(PASSWORD, sharedPreferences.getString(PASSWORD, null));
            return user;
        }

        public void logout(){
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

and this my code for get the `hashmap` item

```
val sessionManager = SessionManager(activity);
                    val user = sessionManager.userDetail
                    val Email = user.get(sessionManager.EMAIL);
                    val Password = user.get(sessionManager.PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Are you calling your createSession() method properly ?

Comment: yes, but i call it at other activity